# Exporting sorted/adjusted data to excel with python

Tags: python, excel, sorting

I have a simple dataset that I have sorted with dataframe based on 'category'.

The sorting has gone all well. But now, I'd like to export the sorted/adjusted dataset in .xlsx format. That is the dataset that has been categorized, not the dataset that is read in excel.

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("python_sorting_test.xlsx",index_col=[1])

df.head()

print(df.sort_index(level=['Category'], ascending=True))

df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Laptop\PycharmProjects\untitled8\export_dataframe.xlsx', header=True)
```

The issue: It doesn't doesn't store the sorted/adjusted dataset.

Comment: Add `inplace` flag otherwise it does not "save" the sort operation.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. `print(df.sort_index(level=['Category'], ascending=True))` just shows the result of sorting and throws it away. Either use `inplace=True` or use `df = df.sort_index(level=['Category'], ascending=True))` to assign the result back

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I noticed the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you doesn't save results of `sort_index`. You can add `inplace=True`

```
print(df.sort_index(level=['Category'], ascending=True, inplace=True))
```

or save results of `df.sort_index`

```
df = df.sort_index(level=['Category'], ascending=True)
```